# Is there a way to link to a SharePoint List with a specific item selected?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view, modern-experience

So let's say we have a SharePoint list with 1000's of items.

And I want to share a link to a single list item.

So the typical step is to use this: `/Lists/YourListTitleHere/DispForm.aspx?ID=1`

But in my case, the List Item details view is not what the user wants to see. They want the list to be displayed with the specific list item visible (and highlighted).

Is there a special List URL format to show a specific item, but not to show the List item details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter SharePoint list views using URL parameters.

For your requirements, try this:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/YourListTitleHere/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=ID&FilterValue1=1
```

Comment: Will that cause the rest of the items in the list to be invisible? Because that would be similar to the list item details view. I'm looking more for a "select page X" where X is the page that has the item on it, and highlight + scrollTo the item.

Comment: Yes, it will filter list view & show only those particular items based on filter criteria.

Comment: The requirement you are referring is not possible with SharePoint out of the box capabilities. As you are using SharePoint online, you have to develop a custom [SPFx web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) to achieve this.

Comment: darn. thanks anyways.